# Building IP Packed using python struct

Tags: python, struct, ip

I am looking to learn more about python and a friend suggested building my own IP packet.

Because I am relativly new to programming I he gave me links to wikipedia (structure of IP packet) but I am a little stuck as to how to create this. I have figured out I need to use `struct` but after this I am not sure. Can someone please direct me to a tutorial or items on the internet which will help me complete this.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/). It's a packet manipulation package for python.